# Words regarding different types of manipulations

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms, vocabulary, idiom-requests

I'm looking for words that describe specific types of manipulation.
The context is board games, but I'm actually looking for more generic words.

Specifically, I'm looking for words that describe manipulations between regions. Technically, everything is a type of "movement", but I want to describe the different directions of movement.

As an example, you have player A, player B, shared area S and vacuum 0 (i.e. create something from nothing).
S -> A: Acquire
A -> S: Place/Deploy
A -> B: Transfer
X -> X: Move
0 -> X: Generate/Produce
X -> 0: Dispose/Discard

Are there any more words that describe specific directions of movement?

I believe these words may work, but I also feel like they are not strict enough. If one hears "Acquire" they may think they can acquire elements from other players, which would be better described with another word (like Transfer)

Comment: I don't understand your *exact* context, but the general term in the context of games is just ***moves*** (which needn't imply any *physical* movement / change of location at all).

Comment: I'm actually looking for *more specific* terms for different types of moves or actions. For example: an action that moves something from a shared area to my personal area could be described as "Acquire". I'm looking for more words like it.

Comment: The situation in your comment could be **invade** or **occupy**.

Comment: I would describe the *inverse* as those terms. I.e. *from* my personal area *to* a shared area. Also, I'm looking for more generic terms. Invade and Occupy specifically describe a hostile type of movement.

Comment: Requests for *lists* are not good for this site, which deals with specific answers to specific questions. Unless you are trying to find a single, specific word, this is too broad a question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more words off the top of my head:

S -> A: Take/Obtain/Discover/Procure

A -> B: Give/Receive/Trade

X -> X: Shift/Relocate

0 -> X: Create/Form/Build

X -> 0: Destroy/Consume/Spend

Comment: Thank you for these ideas, they help. I feel Discover, Build and Spend describe specific *types* of actions and are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Someone reading a game's rules to learn the game needs to learn exactly what they may or may not do, and needs to be confident that they have understood the rules correctly. Possibilities abound, for what a reader might consider plausible. So you as author of the rules need to be clear and unambiguous. What might seem obvious to you or to anyone else involved in designing the game might not be obvious to the reader.

So I would not rely on what you (or anyone else) see as some verb's connotations. If it takes several words rather than just one verb, use those words, to be clear. Make it clear where the player may take the stuff from, and where to. Say that the player may take Xs from the shared area S, or take Xs from another player. Don't just say "may acquire/transfer Xs".